# Expression is not assignable error when using shorter if-statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I'm trying to check if an `NSString` is equal to another. If it is, I want to add an amount, if it's not, I want to subtract. Here is my code:

```
([type isEqualToString:@"Plus"]) ? amount += [amountString doubleValue] : amount -= [amountString doubleValue];
```

I get the error:

> Expression is not assignable

What am I doing wrong, and what does it mean that I can't assign it?

Comment: what is type of your amount variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return a positive or negative value from the ternary expression and add that to amount -

```
amount+= ([type isEqualToString:@"Plus"]) ? [amountString doubleValue] :  -[amountString doubleValue];
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think this is abusing the conditional operator like @The Paramagnetic Croissant said in his answer?

Comment: No, because the point of the ternary operator is to return a value based on a Boolean condition. That is what my code does.  The returned value is then added to amount. The other solutions modify `amount` via a side effect and ignore the returned value from the operator.

Answer (score 1):

`([type isEqualToString:@"Plus"]) ? (amount += [amountString doubleValue]) : (amount -= [amountString doubleValue]);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make some calculations then you should write it in brackets.

try this

```
([type isEqualToString:@"Plus"]) ? (amount -= [amountString doubleValue]) : (amount += [amountString doubleValue]);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `?:` **is not** a "shorter if-statement". It's not even a statement. It's the conditional *operator,* and you get an *expression* if you use it. **And you shouldn't abuse it for a statement like you currently do.**

The problem lies in the precedence of the `?:` operator relative to that of `=`. The expression

```
cond ? var = expr1 : var = expr2;
```

is parsed as

```
((cond) ? (var = expr1) : var) = expr2;
```

where the LHS is not an lvalue, so it doesn't compile. You need to explicitly parenthesize the RHS of the conditional operator, but here you'd be **much better off with a true if statement** in terms of readability:

```
if ([type isEqualToString:@"Plus"]) {
    amount += amountString.doubleValue;
} else {
    amount -= amountString.doubleValue;
}
```